# oracle sql loader skipping columns in .csv file

Tags: oracle11g, sql-loader

*Hi All,
I would greatly appreciate if someone could help me with the SQL loader upload

Issue : I have a .csv file to be uploaded into a table. The file has 18 columns and I need to skip the first 12 columns.
I tried all methods using FILLER on the control file and it is not working.
If anyone can help me with a solution that would be great.*

Below is the control file layout:

OPTIONS ( SKIP=1)
LOAD DATA
INFILE 'C:\SECTHK_1.csv' 
TRUNCATE INTO TABLE "RUN_EXPT_MST"
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'TRAILING NULLCOLS
(Field1 FILLER,

Field2 FILLER,

Field3 FILLER,

Field4 FILLER,

Field5 FILLER,

Field6 FILLER,

Field7 FILLER,

Field8 FILLER,

Field9 FILLER,

Field10 FILLER,

Field11 FILLER,

Field12 FILLER,

RUN_QC_RSLT,

EXPT_FILENAME,

EXPT_NAME,

RUN_END_TIME_TC,

INST_SRL_NUM,

INST_TYP
)

Comment: were you able to fix it?

Comment: Define "not working"!